# How to Install Windows 8.1 Pro on ASUS N46

Tags: windows, windows-8, installation, windows-8.1-upgrade

I am installing Windows 8.1 Pro onto my ASUS N46JV laptop. At step "Which type of installation do you want?" there are 2 options:

```
Upgrade: Install Windows and keep files, settings, and application
Custom: Install Windows only (advanced)
```

I chose option 1 then Compatibility report shows "The computer started using the Windows installation media. Remove the installation media and restart your computer so that Windows start normally. Then, insert the installation media and restart the upgrade. (Do not select ICustom (advanced)I to perform an upgrade. ICustom (advanced)I installs a new copy of Windows and deletes your programs and settings.)

Then I chose option 2, at step "Where do you want to install Windows?" There are 3 choices:

```
Drive 0 Partition 1: System Reserved
Drive 0 Partition 2
Drive 0 Partition 3
```

I cannot install on partition 2 and 3, because "Windows cannot be installed to this disk. The selected disk has an MBR partition table. On EFI system, windows can only be installed to GPT disks."

I once installed Windows 8.1 Pro on my laptop ACER Aspire 4736Z without any problems. I need an explanation with these 2 cases, why does this happen and how to solve it?

Comment: What operating system are you upgrading from.  If its Windows 8 why not just use the Windows Store method?

Comment: The error message explains the problem.  You have to boot the disk using the legacy support and/or just use the Windows Store method.  Your problem is your disk has a MBR partition but your booting the disk in EFI mode which only supports GPT partitions.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't know how to use Windows Store method, is it simple? I only have the Windows 8.1 CD installation and just know install by this way

Comment: If you have Windows 8 installed you just select and install the Windows 8.1 update.  Everything that needs to happen will happen in the background.  If you don't have Windows 8 installed then the installation disk is your only option and you need to convert your partition to GPT not MBR.  Update your question to reflect which Windows your upgrading from because that **still** is not clear.

Answer (score -1):

For the first option: you can only upgrade windows from actively running windows (old versions) and cannot upgrade from booting a Disc at startup.

Second option
The windows installation disc you have has an EFI enabled boot manager instead of MBR enabled boot manager of either x32 or x64 bit editions. Although a disc could contain MBR+EFI boot manager in a single disc x32 or x64 bit. Your installation disc only contains EFI boot manager (which can only be installed on a GPT formatted disc drive (Fully formatted hard disc not just a partition) or there could be MBR boot manager but your bios settings overrides the EFI boot manager over MBR boot manager. You just have to find "UEFI boot" option (find that option that talks about UEFI in the bios) and disable it to get the MBR boot manager. If there is only EFI bm then your only option is to format the hard disc (format it and it will be GPT formatted automatically) and clean install windows 8.1

Also EFI boot manager is visual boot manager (just like a GUI enabled boot menu).

Comment: Sorry I don't get it clearly, do you mean that my disc only contains EFI boot manager? should I use CD installation that support MBR? I've checked boot option from BIOS there is no UEFI boot option.

Comment: @willy "Windows cannot be installed to this disk. The selected disk has an MBR partition table on EFI system windows can only be installed to GPT disks" This only means that your system is configured to install only EFI boot manager. If this is the error then, UEFI is enabled in your bios and only way to install windows is to disable it.ASUS PCs/laptops are pre-configured for UEFI enabled boot partition. You don't have an EFI enabled installation disc. This disc only contain MBR enabled boot partition. You have to get a disc which has EFI enabled partition. You can google about EFI bios.

Answer (score -1):

I think you may need to change your partition to GPT with a HDD Manager. For Example "Paragon HDD Manager" would be good. However you may face "**Data Loss**" (in spite of the fact that you don't want to lose your data!!!!). So make sure you make a backup of your files before doing anything. Here is the link about Paragon HDD Manager and it's services : http://www.paragon-software.com/home/pm-professional/comparison.html

And why was it OK in your previous Laptop ?! That's probably because the Acer laptop had GPT structure but your new Asus does not.

I'll be glad if this was helpfull.

Comment: I've just delete the partition, format the partition and split it into 2 drives. I can install Windows 8.1, so does this mean that my partition is GPT already? but after that, there is "windows 8.1 secureboot isn't configured correctly" appear in the right bottom of windows

Answer (score -2):

I got the same message when i tried to install Windows 8 Pro on my ASUS D550CA-RS31 which came with Windows 8. After some struggle for way, way too many hours, I was able to resolve the problem. Knowing where to go and what to do for me was the key. So hopefully someone else will find this helpful and save them 24 hrs.

I had Window 8 and I had the same problem when trying to upgrade to Windows 8 Pro. What helped me was going to Search on my Windows 8 machine. I searched for Add Features. I followed all the steps. It was straightforward and it simply asked me for my Product Key. I put it in. It verified it and told me it might take some time. I waited 30+ minutes and then contacted Microsoft Support. She told me to restart my computer manually. It was hung up in the Add Feature section. Then it started applying the updates. After some time, it completed with Windows 8 Pro installed. I then upgraded from Windows 8 Pro to Windows 8.1 Pro.

I hope this helps. I spent a whole day and all last night trying to figure this out.

I was really afraid I would have to repurchase Windows 8 Pro or 8.1. If you have a key to Windows 8 Pro you can ask Microsoft Support if it can be updated through Windows Store.

Comment: I assume you used a non-OEM key because an OEM Windows 8.x license isn't something you typical know or need to know and if thats the case then this answer isn't all that helpful to somebody with an OEM machine like the author was.